# Angular ngModel в цикле

Tags: angular2, angular4

Есть компонент который выводится в цикле `n` количество раз.
В нем еще два компонента которые связаны двухторонней привязкой.
При изменении данных хотяб в одном соответсвенно данные менются во всех.

Мне нужно чтоб данные были связаны только на одной итерации:

```
<app-root *ngFor="let item of anyList;>

 <app-first-component><app-first-component>
 <app-second-component><app-second-component>

<app-root>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста направление в котором нужно действовать

Comment: покажите ваш код пожалуйста

Comment: `app-root` у вас корневой компонент? где у вас двусторонний байдинг?

Comment: Между app-first-component и app-second-component

Comment: я вижу просто селектор компонента, но ни одного инпута и атпута, либо директивы `ngModel`

Comment: Да, я схематично написал.  Думал тут будет какой-то очевидный ответ.  Вроде передайте  item в компоненты. Ок, подготовлю реальный пример